# GDB-peda searchmem command

Tags: gdb

I cannot find example on usage of 'searchmem' command in gdb-peda, in standard gdb the command 'find' moreover can be used to find instructions of interest, this way:

```
(gdb)find /b start_address,end_address,opcode1,opcode2,..,opcodeN
```

for example to search the gadget "pop ebx ; ret" i would type in gdb:

```
(gdb)find /b start_address,end_address,0x59,0xc3
```

How to play with gdb peda to do this?

UPDATE:
with ropsearch i can hit this.

```
(gdb-peda)ropsearch "pop ebx ; ret" libc
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code you can pass `searchmem` a regular expression pattern so you are able to pass in your list of opcodes that way.

The relevant section:

```
    def searchmem(self, start, end, search, mem=None):
    """
    Search for all instances of a pattern in memory from start to end
    Args:
        - start: start address (Int)
        - end: end address (Int)
        - search: string or python regex pattern (String)
        - mem: cached mem to not re-read for repeated searches (raw bytes)
    Returns:
        - list of found result: (address(Int), hex encoded value(String))
```

https://github.com/longld/peda/blob/master/peda.py#L1872